# Finding the last and first day of months between two specific date using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with the columns "buying date" and "selling date".

Lets say that the first row in the dataframe can look like:

| buying date | selling date |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-01-04 | 2000-04-15 |

And I want to create a new dataframe that starts with the buying date, ends with the selling date and between them i want the first date and last date of every month between the buying date and the selling date. So it would give me something like:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2000-01-04 |
| 2000-01-31 |
| 2000-02-01 |
| 2000-02-28 |
| 2000-03-01 |
| 2000-03-31 |
| 2000-04-01 |
| 2000-04-15 |

Does anyone have a smart solution to this?

Thank you!

Comment: You want a new dataframe for every row in your initial dataset?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
ms = pd.date_range('2000-01-04', '2000-04-15', freq='MS')
me = pd.date_range('2000-01-04', '2000-04-15', freq='M')
df.T.set_index(0).index.union(ms).union(me).to_frame().sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                    0
2000-01-04 2000-01-04
2000-01-31 2000-01-31
2000-02-01 2000-02-01
2000-02-29 2000-02-29
2000-03-01 2000-03-01
2000-03-31 2000-03-31
2000-04-01 2000-04-01
2000-04-15 2000-04-15
```

Comment: Not sure of your exact needs, but this is a roadmap to a potential solution for you.

Comment: Thanks you @Scott Boston. That is what I was searching for. Would you possibly also know how to determine if the first day or last day in the month is a business day, and if not you will instead choose the next business day? For example if 2000-04-01 is a Sunday, you will instead get 2000-04-02.

Comment: Yes, use BMS and BM for buinss month start and business month end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how smart this is but it should work.

- starting with the beginning date create a date range using the [MonthBegin DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)
- starting with the beginning date create a date range using the MonthEnd DateOffset
- interleave them

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'buying date':pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-04']),
                   'selling date':pd.to_datetime(['2000-04-15'])})
start,end = df.iloc[0]
lasts = pd.date_range(start,end,freq='M')
firsts = pd.date_range(start,end,freq='MS')
middle = np.vstack((lasts,firsts)).ravel('F')
start = np.array(start,dtype='datetime64[ns]')
end = np.array(end,dtype='datetime64[ns]')

s = pd.Series(np.hstack([start,middle,end]))
```

---

```
>>> print(s)
0   2000-01-04
1   2000-01-31
2   2000-02-01
3   2000-02-29
4   2000-03-01
5   2000-03-31
6   2000-04-01
7   2000-04-15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import calendar

def main():
    start_date = date(2021, 1, 4)
    end_date = date(2021, 4, 15)

    dates = [start_date]
    for month in range(start_date.month, end_date.month+1):
        first_day_of_month = date(2021, month, 1)
        last_day_of_month = date(2021, month, calendar.monthrange(2021, month)[1])
        print(first_day_of_month)
        print(last_day_of_month)
        dates.append(first_day_of_month)
        dates.append(last_day_of_month)

    dates.append(end_date)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates})

    print(df)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```